# Youtube upload fails with "insufficientPermissions" even with valid token

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm getting "insufficient permission" as error string when posting a youtube video with youtube API. The token obtained with Oauth2 when tested with curl or by checking on https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?access_token=... seems all good.

Tried changing scope, refrehsing the token but i have no clue why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out that the google account you are using also HAS a youtube account. Took me longer than i'd like to admit to realize that...